# ISM RF link problem

Tags: rf, wireless, manchester-coding

I've established an RF link using TWS-CS-2 as a transmitter and AM-HRR3-433 as a receiver.

*The carrier frequency : 433.92MHz.*

*Modulation type : ASK.*

*ATtiny25 to generate and decode Manchester encoded signal.*

The code was tested with two ATtinys directly connected and worked flawlessly.

Then I tried wireless communication and strange things started to happen.

I have two types of signal (two four digit numbers). One is always received and seen on a serial monitor, the other one can't be seen most of the time.

I would appreciate any help.

UPDATE

I used Manchester library from http://mchr3k.github.io/arduino-libs-manchester/

and Arduino Uno Rev.3 as ISP

Tx code

```
    #include <Manchester.h>

#define TxPin 2
short int switch_on = 1678;
short int switch_off = 8435; // !!!Signal that is not detected most of the time
short int flag;
short int ON_Button;
short int OFF_Button;


void setup()
{
  man.setupTransmit(TxPin, MAN_1200);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  ON_Button = digitalRead(0);
  OFF_Button = digitalRead(1);

  if(ON_Button==OFF_Button){digitalWrite(3, LOW);return;}

  if(ON_Button==HIGH) {flag=1;digitalWrite(3, HIGH);}
  if(OFF_Button==HIGH) {flag=2;digitalWrite(3, HIGH);}

  if(flag==1)
  man.transmit(switch_on);
  if(flag==2)
  man.transmit(switch_off);
}
```

Rx code

```
    #include <Manchester.h>

#define RX_PIN 2

void setup() {
  man.setupReceive(RX_PIN, MAN_1200);
  man.beginReceive();
  pinMode(0,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(0,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (man.receiveComplete()) {
    short int m = man.getMessage();
    man.beginReceive();
    if(m==1678){digitalWrite(0,HIGH);}
    if(m==8435){digitalWrite(0,LOW);} // !!!Signal that is not detected most of the time
    m = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please specify the numbers, which work and which do not. Also source code would help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It turned out the data rate was too high for my receiver. 
I switched from 1200 bps to 300 bps.
Now everything works smoothly.